# Code wont loop through sheets as well as rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code to loop through all sheets in a workbook, apart from 1, and add a column which is a concatenation of 3 others. This seems to loop through all the rows for one worksheet, but not the others in the book

```
Sub addConcats()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim rw As Range
  Dim RowCount As Integer

  'Run through worksheets
  Dim x As Long
  Sheet1.Select
  For x = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(x).Name <> "VAT Transaction Report" Then Sheets(x).Select 
    Replace:=False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For y = 2 To LastRow
      'Concat
      ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 20).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 7).Value & 
ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 9).Value & ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 12).Value
    Next y
  Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Inside your y loop you are referencing ActiveSheet.  This is why you are only updating a single sheet.

Comment: @BrianMStafford In the `x` loop, the `Sheets(x).Select` will have changed the sheet.  Still inefficient though

Comment: @Dave You are correct.  I missed that line of code!

Comment: @Dave - The "select" on a Sheet is not the same as the "Activate" method.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, for your `For` loop to take into consideration the `Sheets(x)` you are trying to update:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

For x = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(x).Name <> "VAT Transaction Report" Then
        With Sheets(x)                            
            LastRow = .UsedRange.Row - 1 + .UsedRange.Rows.Count            
            For y = 2 To LastRow
                'Concat
                .Cells(y, 20).Value = .Cells(y, 7).Value & .Cells(y, 9).Value & .Cells(y, 12).Value
            Next y
        End With
    End If
Next x
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to select each worksheet for this, or run with x and y.

```
Sub addConcats()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
For Each sh in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "VAT Transaction Report" Then 
        LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        For y = 2 To LastRow
            'Concat
            sh.Cells(y, 20).Value = sh.Cells(y, 7).Value & sh.Cells(y, 9).Value & sh.Cells(y, 12).Value
        Next y
    End If
Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you select a sheet, but do not use Sheet.Activate. Next you use ActiveSheet. It is better to avoid selecting sheets altogether and just work against a Worksheet object (sh variable)

Try the following:

```
Sub addConcats()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

For x = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Set sh = Sheets(x)
    If sh.Name <> "VAT Transaction Report" Then
        LastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For y = 2 To LastRow
        'Concat
            sh.Cells(y, 20).Value = sh.Cells(y, 7).Value & sh.Cells(y, 9).Value & sh.Cells(y, 12).Value
        Next y
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```